# Determine logged in user ID in Jenkins workflow

Tags: jenkins-workflow

Is there any way to determine the currently logged in user in workflow? In our traditional jobs we use [Build User Vars Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin) but that doesn't appear to be available in workflow.

Answer (score 0):

[JENKINS-26953](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26953) tracks the integration.

In the meantime you could try

```
def cause = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause)
if (cause != null) {
    def user = cause.userId ?: 'anonymous'
    echo "started by ${user}"
} else {
    echo "started some other way"
}
```

Note that this code will not work when run from the Groovy sandbox, as it accesses Jenkins APIs directly, so it is not suitable for a secured installation.